# Monitoring Google Container Engine Disk Use in Percent with Stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, diskspace, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is there a way of checking the disk usage for volumes/pd's in the google cluster with stackdriver?
We found a way to check for bytes used, but this is pretty useless when there is no way to compare it to the limits (usage in percent)...
Also there is no bytes free metric.

I read about custom metrics, but did not understand how those might help here. Is there a way of adding a policy which does what we need (possibly via the api)?

Comment: Interesting point. Are you worried about the local disk (because unused docker images get garbage collected) or the free space remaining on Persistent Disks you create for volumes?

Comment: No, local disk is not relevant to us. We want to monitor only persistent disks created by kubernetes in order to see if any application volume might become full. Or other pd's created manually...
My quite dirty solution would now be to build a docker image that contains the stackdriver agent and the add it to every pod with volumes to monitor... I would prefer a better way but this would be a workaround...
But I can not understand why there is bytes_used and bytes_total but no bytes_free or percent_used on container disks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find this information using:

Metric: `container/container/disk/bytes_total`

Filter: `project_id: <id>` `pod_id: <id>`
`device_name: Volume:<name_of_volume>`

You can use similar metric for bytes used.

Comment: Sure, this is indeed available information but does not help as bytes_used gives an absolute number of bytes which can not be compared with the available bytes in any policy. So there is no way of getting alerts when the disk is full.